# How can i sum of array's elements with threads in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

I work on this but i did not find solution of my problem. 
This is my code. This code give an error on pthread_create and pthread_join lines. I tried everything to fix this problem but i cannot do this.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <pthread.h>
  #define array_size 1000
  #define no_threads 10

 float a[array_size];
 int global_index = 0;
 int sum = 0;
 pthread_t mutex_t ,mutex1;

 void *slave(void *ignored)
{
 int local_index, partial_sum = 0;
 do {
    pthread_t mutex_t ,lock(mutex1);
      local_index = global_index;
      global_index++;
    pthread_t mutex ,unlock(mutex1);

    if (local_index < array_size)
        partial_sum += *(a + local_index);
}
while
 (local_index < array_size);

pthread_t mutex , lock(mutex1);
sum += partial_sum;
pthread_t mutex_t , unlock(mutex1);

 return 0;
}

 main()
 {
  int i;
  pthread_t thread_x[10];
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);

  for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
   a[i] = i+1;

  for (i = 0; i < no_threads ; i++)
  pthread_create(&thread_x[i] , NULL, slave,NULL);

  for (i = 0; i < no_threads; i++)
    pthread_join(&thread_x[i] , NULL);


  printf("The sum of 1 to %d is %d\n", array_size, sum);
}
```

Comment: I dont know CodeBlock gave me an error on create and join lines but i didnt find out what error is.

Comment: See the error on CodeBlock and write it here.
And i think: "pthread_t mutex_t ,lock(mutex1);" is not valid

Comment: Your `main()` function has no return type. That should be at least a warning. The fact that you turn off compiler warnings means either 1. You don't care about the quality of the code. 2. Or you don't know that you can make the compiler emit warnings. If you turn on warnings probably more problems will become apparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have updated your code(pt1.c) I think you are looking for something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define array_size 1000
#define no_threads 10

float a[array_size];
int global_index = 0;
int sum = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex1;

void *slave(void *ignored)
{
    int local_index, partial_sum = 0;
    do {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        local_index = global_index;
        global_index++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

        if (local_index < array_size)
            partial_sum += *(a + local_index);
    }
    while(local_index < array_size);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    sum += partial_sum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

    return 0;
}

main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t thread_x[10];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        a[i] = i+1;

    for (i = 0; i < no_threads ; i++)
        pthread_create(&thread_x[i] , NULL, slave,NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < no_threads; i++)
        pthread_join(thread_x[i] , NULL);

    printf("The sum of 1 to %d is %d\n", array_size, sum);
}
```

You should compile this code as
**gcc -pthread pt1.c**

**output** :

The sum of 1 to 1000 is 500500

Comment: Isn't it waste of resources that `global_index` exceeds the `array_size` as the whole process is done in parallel, regardless of the `if (local_index < array_size)` statement?

Comment: The method yields different results when I try to increase the number of array_size to 1000000 or any number greater that 1000.